# Type error when chaining Q.ninvoke

Tags: node.js, mongodb, q

There is an error when I was trying to use Q to chain `mongodb` functions in Node.js as follow:

```
Q.ninvoke(MongoClient, 'connect', 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb')
.then(function(db){
    return Q
    .ninvoke(db, 'createCollection', 'mycollection')
    .ninvoke(db.collection('mycollection'), 'createIndex', {id: 1}) // error occurs here
    .ninvoke(db, 'close')
    .then(function(){...})
});
```

The error message I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
  at Promise.post (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:1157:36)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:784:41)
  at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:600:44
  at runSingle (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:133:13)
  at flush (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:121:13)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

According to the message, line 1157 in q.js is about:

```
Q.fulfill = fulfill;
function fulfill(value) {
    return Promise({
    ...
    "post": function (name, args) {
        if (name === null || name === void 0) {
            return value.apply(void 0, args);
        } else {
            return value[name].apply(value, args); // error occurs here: line 1157
        }
    }
```

Although I have little idea what's going on inside Q, I guess `db.collection('mycollection')` is not passed correctly as `value` in line 1157. I've raised this issue on the [Github of q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/691) but haven't got any response.

If I change the code like this, everything works fine again:

```
Q.ninvoke(MongoClient, 'connect', 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb')
.then(function(db){
    return Q
    .ninvoke(db, 'createCollection', 'mycollection')
    .then(function(){
        return Q.ninvoke(db.collection('mycollection'), 'createIndex', {id: 1}) // no error this time
        .then(function(){
             return Q.ninvoke(db, 'close').then(function(){...});
        });
    });
});
```

However, here comes a pyramid which grows along with the chain. I think Q should have supported chaining `ninvoke` like the first example.

In short, my question is whether there is misunderstanding the of use Q, or there is actually a bug in Q?

Package versions I used:
node.js: v0.10.36
Q: 1.4.0
mongodb: 2.0.31

### Update

I rule out the factor of MongoDB and narrow down the scope of the problem as follow:

```
var TestClass = function (name){
};

TestClass.prototype.printName = function (callback) {
    console.log('printName called');
    return callback(null);
};

var test = new TestClass('test object');

test.printName(function (err) {
    test.printName(function (err) {
        console.log('callback called');
    });
});
```

In this case, the output should be:

```
$ node q-test.js
printName called
printName called
callback called
```

But if I use Q as follow:

```
Q.ninvoke(test, 'printName')
.ninvoke(test, 'printName')
.then(function(){
    console.log('callback called');
})
.done();
```

It turns out the output with an error like this:

```
$ node test.js
printName called

/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined
    at Promise.post (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:1161:29)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
    at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Comment: I have a very similar stack trace (slightly different line numbers) but am new to Q. Did you every figure this out?

Comment: @DavidKassa - See my answer on this question if you still have your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR version**: When called in a chain as opposed to directly as `Q.ninvoke()` the object whose function is to be invoked comes from the result of the prior function in the chain, not from the first parameter to the `qpromise.ninvoke()` call.

**Elaboration:** 
While I initially thought from a quick glance that the issue was that in your original code, the collection itself would not yet have been created when `db.collection('mycollection')` is called in the following line. In your correct/working version, this would be addressed, because the `ninvoke` binding isn't happening until after the collection has been created. I now see that the general problem is how you are calling .ninvoke() past its initial use in a chain.

Your updated example wasn't directly helpful, because you are using `ninvoke()` but not using a node-style callback form with it, so you were bound to get different sort of errors.

At least referring to your new non-Mongo example the root problem is how you are using `.ninvoke()` in your subsequent calls. After the initial `Q.ninvoke()` the subsequent `.ninvoke()` calls when applied to the returned promise, uses the return value of the promise as the first parameter. This is maybe more easily illustrated than anything else, please review the change I made to your "printName" example:

```
var TestClass = function (name){ };

TestClass.prototype.printName = function (callback) {
    console.log('printName called');
    return callback(null,this);     // node style callback, also return this
};

var test = new TestClass('test object');

Q.ninvoke(test, 'printName')
//  in the lines below, the result of the prior line is the "implied" first
// parameter to ninvoke();
.ninvoke('printName')
.ninvoke('printName')   
.then(function(){
    console.log('callback called');
})
.done();
```

Hopefully this illustrates what is going on.

Returning to your original quesiton, while I am not a Mongo user, from looking at the docs for it, it appears that createCollection in fact returns the collection, so you could probably amend your earlier code:

```
return Q
.ninvoke(db, 'createCollection', 'mycollection')
.ninvoke(db.collection('mycollection'), 'createIndex', {id: 1}) // error occurs here
```

Into

```
return Q
.ninvoke(db, 'createCollection', 'mycollection')
.ninvoke('createIndex', {id: 1}) // error *should not occur* here :-)
```

However, I am not sure what you will want to do about the "close" since presumably createIndex will not just return a reference to the DB. I don't know the API but presumably you could use Q's `.get()` [or related functions](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#over-the-wire) to get to it and then pass along to the `.ninvoke('close')`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/134) for a discussion of the implementation in Q, which also has a link to the changes made to implement it and you can see exactly how it is working.

Comment: Mongodb driver needs not to create collection before using it, and the collection object returned from `db.collection('mycollection')` is not `undefined` as well. Also, I found the crux of the problem may not be related to Mongodb driver. I've updated the question above.

Comment: @CHI-IHUANG - Thanks for the clarification - I am not a Mongo user, and have seem similar flow causes issues in other DB tools.I'll review your updated question.

Comment: @CHI-IHUANG - Sorry I got called away for a bit. I looked at your updated question. Will update my answer.

Comment: Your explanation gives me a clear idea where the error roots. Thanks for your detailed elaboration :)